# Maximum area of a triangle when perimeter is fixed.

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, area, geometric-inequalities

I can't solve the following problem:

Show that amongst all triangles with perimeter  $3p,$ the equilateral triangle with side $p$ has the largest area. Further show that $9p^2\ge 12\sqrt{3}\Delta.$

I have got that the area is maximum when $ab+bc+ca$ is maximum and $abc$ is minimum (by using Heron's Formula). I am stuck at this point.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\Delta$?

Comment: $\Delta$ is area of the triangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Heron's formula
$$ 16\Delta^2 = (a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) \tag{1}$$
and by the AM-GM inequality
$$ (-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) \leq \left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3 \tag{2} $$
Equality is attained only at $a=b=c$.

Comment: (+1) A good and elegant solution, Thanks. But the second part of the question?

Comment: @user333900: for the second part you just have to put $a=b=c=p$, getting $16\Delta^2 \leq 3p^4$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio It isn't said that $a=b=c=p$. $p$ is arbitrary.

Comment: @user333900: you have that the perimeter is fixed, equal to $3p$, and equality in $(2)$ is attained only at $a=b=c$. Given $a+b+c=3p$, it follows that $a=b=c=p$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio No, I meant for all $p$ such that $3p$ is perimeter of triangle with area $\Delta$ prove that $9p^2\ge 12\sqrt{3}\Delta$.

Comment: @user333900: for all $p$ such that $a+b+c=3p$, $(2)$ holds as an equality iff $a=b=c$, i.e. iff $a=b=c=p$, and gives $16\Delta^2\leq 3p^4$.